# RippleDrawable - Show Ripple Effect programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

I have a view with like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And ripple.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</ripple>
```

Everything works great. When i touch the view it gives me Ripple Effect.
What i am looking for is to start the ripple animation on the view from code repeatedly. To show it as a indeterminate progress. So waves keeps on rippling.

Something like

```
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        RippleDrawable drawable = (RippleDrawable) button.getBackground();
        drawable.showRipples(true, true); // <-- This is needed

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
    }
};
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`RippleDrawable` responds to pressed and focused states, with the former giving the ripple animation that you're looking for. You can toggle pressed state on the host view using `View.setPressed(boolean)`.

```
Runnable pressRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.setPressed(true);
        button.postOnAnimationDelayed(unpressRunnable, 250);
    }
};

Runnable unpressRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.setPressed(false);
        button.postOnAnimationDelayed(pressRunnable, 250);
    }
};
```

Keep in mind that the user touching the `Button` toggles the pressed state as well, so you might want to remove or re-post your runnables in an `OnTouchListener`.

If desired, you can control the ripple position using `Drawable.setHotspot(float, float)` or, on API 22+, `View.dispatchDrawableHotspotChanged(float, float)` and passing view-relative `(x, y)` coordinates.

Comment: Drawable.setHotspot(float, float) has to be called every time to keep it constant. It gets reset somehow.

Comment: So bad solution. (Why ?) dinamically + runnables + observers not are good refresh %cpu (RecycleView)

Comment: Brilliant!! Brilliant answer!! Exactly what i was looking for!! Thanks a million!!!! (y)